Opposites attract
She: I kinda look like a tiny bit of water
He: Cool, me too!
She: I'm down
He: Ok, I'm actually up
She: I'm mostly dark
He: I'm mostly light but I'm a little dark too
She: And I'm a little light!

Which two had this conversation?

The conversation is between...

 Yin and yang - the two halves represented in the following diagram:



 These two entities represent two complementary-yet-opposing forces that together form a dynamic system. This is reflected in the title, which also refers to their opposing black-and-white nature in colour terms.

She: I kinda look like a tiny bit of water
He: Cool, me too!

 The two halves of this diagram both resemble a teardrop or water droplet in shape.

She: I'm down
He: Ok, I'm actually up

 She is yin, the darker half of the diagram typically depicted as the bottom ('down') part. He is yang, the lighter half of the diagram typically depicted as the top ('up') part.

She: I'm mostly dark
He: I'm mostly light but I'm a little dark too
She: And I'm a little light!

 The mainly 'dark' area (she) of the diagram is yin, whilst the mainly 'light' area (he) is yang. Being 'a little' of the opposite colour refers to the small circle of the opposite shade entirely surrounded within each shape.


Yup, that's it!
